# How can i train multiple times an SVM classifier from sklearn in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I was wandering if it possible to train the SVM classifier from sklearn in Python many times inside a for loop. I have in mind something like the following:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    data = np.load(somedata)
    labels = np.load(somelabels)
    C = SVC()
    C.fit(data, labels)
    joblib.dump(C, 'somefolderpath/Model.pkl')
```

I want my model to be trained for each one of the 10 data and their labels. Is that possible in that way or do i have to append all the data and labels into two corresponding arrays containing the whole data and labels from my 10 items?

**EDITED**: If i want to train a separate classifier for each subject. Then how would the above syntax look like? Is my edit correct?
And when i want to load the specific trained classifier for my specific subject, can i do:

```
C = joblib.load('somefolderpath/Model.pkl')
idx = C.predict(data)
```

?

Comment: Of course you can. The question of whether that is a good idea depends on what you want to achieve. What is it?

Comment: Does `somedata` and `somelabels` depend on `i` or why exactly do you want to train multiple instances of `SVC`? Are you looking for hyperparameter optimisation?

Comment: i just want to train my model based on data from 10 different persons. The question is if its better and possible to do it in every iteration like this or if its better to put them all together and how.

Comment: What kind of data do you have, and what do you want to predict? This question largely depends on the given scenario.

Comment: embedding vectors and i want to perform supervised spectral clustering

Comment: SVMs don't do supervised spectral clustering.

Comment: for the thing i want to do it can be done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `fit` on any scikit-learn estimator will forget all the previously seen data. So if you want to make predictions using all of your data (all ten patients), you need to concatenate it first.
In particular, if each `somelabels` contains only a single label, the code doesn't make sense and might even error because only one class is present.

Comment: each data and labels are lists with their corresponding arrays containing data and labels. What would you propose to do?

Comment: What are the labels? As Matt said above, it depends on what you want to do. Do you want to learn across patients or not?

Comment: yes i do. the labels contain according arrays of zeros, ones etc with the same size as each one of the items in the data list for each patient. For example,

Comment: yes i do. the labels contain according arrays of zeros, ones etc with the same size as each one of the items in the data list for each patient. For example, len(data1)=10 then len(labels)=10 and data[0] corresponds to labels[0], data[1] to labels[1] etc. The thing is that for each data, its corresponding data{i} has the same labels{i} for each patient.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your last statement. It sounds like you want to concatenate the data. You have to to learn across patients.

Comment: ok i did that using extend() to make for the data and the labels to form 2 big lists.