# What if i train classifier two time?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

If I train a classifier two times, like:

```
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Will it overwrite the existing classifier or will it just train it one time?

Comment: It will overwrite.

Comment: Just to clear. Will it be same as i train classifier two time right?

Comment: Depends on what type of classifier you are using. If it's something like random forest, you will get a different model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `clf` will be fit with the last data you try to fit it with. See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884168/9458191 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `.fit(...)` on a classifier, it will only retain the new fit, essentially overwriting any previous training.

If you are using an entirely different dataset, the resulting classfier will obviously be different than before the second `.fit(...)` call. If you are using the **same** dataset, then the classifier may or may not be any different. Some classifiers are deterministic in training, if this is the case then they should not be any different. Some classifiers are non-deterministic, however, and those could have different results during the second training.

Comment: What if i save classifier and load it and train classifier. Will it be same?

Comment: If you save a trained classifier and load it (properly, see [model persistence](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)), it should be the same as it was saved. If you then call `.fit(...)` on the loaded classifier, it will lose the previously-trained model